# how to add a value to cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am using the spreadsheet to do inventory- scanning  parts in bin
I am trying to add a A2 Value next to the  `(Target.Row, 5)(row 6)`

how do I make A2 or A9 or the next scan Value show up on Column F so if column E & F don't match I know the part is sitting on the wrong bin

I have tried `.Value = Target.Worksheet.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value` but not working

[image]

Here is my complete code

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Or Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not SheetExists("WarehouseInventory") Then Exit Sub

    Dim Result As Variant
    Set Result = Sheets("WarehouseInventory").Cells.Range("E:E").Find(Target)

    If Result Is Nothing Then
       Target.Worksheet.Cells(Target.Row, 2) = "Data New Bin"
    Else
        Target.Worksheet.Cells(Target.Row, 2) = Result.Worksheet.Cells(Result.Row, 4)
        Target.Worksheet.Cells(Target.Row, 3) = Result.Worksheet.Cells(Result.Row, 5)
        Target.Worksheet.Cells(Target.Row, 4) = Result.Worksheet.Cells(Result.Row, 6)
        Target.Worksheet.Cells(Target.Row, 5) = Result.Worksheet.Cells(Result.Row, 7)
    End If

End Sub

Public Function SheetExists(SheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    SheetExists = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = SheetName Then SheetExists = True
    Next ws
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this an example how you can achieve required result

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim x&, y&
If Target.Column = 6 Then
    y = 5: x = Target.Row
    While Cells(x, y) <> "": x = x - 1: Wend
    If Cells(Target.Row, 5) <> "" Then Cells(Target.Row, 6) = Cells(x, 1)
End If
End Sub
```

output

[image]

## UPDATE

here your updated code, tested, works fine, insert it into `"Cycle Count"` sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim x&, y&, Result As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Application.EnableEvents = 0
    If Target.Count > 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = 1
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, [A1:A99999]) Is Nothing Then
        With ThisWorkbook
            For Each ws In .Worksheets
                If ws.Name = "WarehouseInventory" Then
                    Set ws = .Worksheets("WarehouseInventory")
                    Set Result = ws.[E:E].Find(Target.Value)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next ws
            If Result Is Nothing Then
                Target.Offset(, 1).Value = "Data New Bin"
                Application.EnableEvents = 1
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Target.Offset(, 1).Value = ws.Range(Result.Address).Offset(, -1).Value
                Target.Offset(, 2).Value = ws.Range(Result.Address).Value
                Target.Offset(, 3).Value = ws.Range(Result.Address).Offset(, 1).Value
                Target.Offset(, 4).Value = ws.Range(Result.Address).Offset(, 2).Value
                y = 5: x = Target.Row
                While .ActiveSheet.Cells(x, y) <> "": x = x - 1: Wend
                Target.Offset(, 5).Value = .ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value
            End If
        End With
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = 1
End Sub
```

sample file here http://www.filedropper.com/book1_5

Answer (score 1):

What about `Target.Worksheet.Cells(Target.Row, 6).Value = Target.Worksheet.Cells(Target.Row,1).Value` ?

If you want only A2, in all rows substitute Target.Row with 2

Comment: No that is not it, I don't want row 1 value in row 6. - I am scanning a bin# then serial#'s  once I am don't with that bin then I go to the next bin and do the same, I am doing this to see if the Serial # is sitting on the wrong bin. I am trying to compare E & F Cells to see if the match

Comment: Okay. You can compare the values in the two colums in several different ways. I suggest to use a simple VLOOKUP and check what it returns. If you like to do it with your own code, a for loop inside a for loop could do the trick. I'm on my iPhone so, I can't provide an example.

Comment: Is something not working in your code? or do you want additional code added to the original code? maybe show another pic of the other sheet and the desired result in the first sheet. Right now you have A2 highlighted and column F highlighted, it doesn't make sense with the code you provided.

Comment: my code is working I just need additional code added that can take A2 value add to column F